# Password rotation for kafka acl passwords which are stored in zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

How to handle password rotation for kafka acls passwords?

Users cant access the kafka cluster without authentication, we are adding the user(& password) to zookeeper and adding the respective acls for the user.

Now i have a requirement for passwords rotation for these uses passwords which are stored in zookeeper

Comment: 1) Zookeeper isnt a requirement for Kafka auth. For example, if you use MSK, then you can use IAM roles to configure users, and rotate credentials using that. 2) How are you rotating credentials for anything else, and why are you treating Kafka differently?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rotate passwords in that case without a chance of downtime (auth failures).
Ignoring the small chance of auth failures, what you could do is the following:

1. Change the passwords in the zookeeper using the same command that you had used to create the username/password.
2. Then, change your applications to use the new passwords.

Downside to this approach is that if your app restarts between steps 1 & 2 (i.e. the zookeeper has been updated with the new password, but the app is using the old password), then the app will get auth failure errors.